# invalid use of incomplete type in handling exceptions

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

How to implement the following without troubles connected with "invalid use of incomplete type"?

```
class A { // line#10
    /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
    // more fields of the following functionality exist, storing data about object A's state.
    int SomeField;
    class Exception {
        /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
        public: enum ProblemCase { /*(...) */ };
        protected: Exception( ProblemCase issue, int additionalData ) { /*(...)*/ } // line#29
        friend Exception A::BuildException( ProblemCase ); // line#34
    };
    inline Exception BuildException( Exception::ProblemCase issue ) {
        return Exception( issue, SomeField ); // line#99
    }
};
```

#### updade: error log:

```
A.hpp:34:72: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A’
A.hpp:10:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class A’
A.hpp: In member function ‘A::Exception A::BuildException(A::Exception::ProblemCase)’:
A.hpp:29:20: error: ‘A::Exception::Exception(A::Exception::ProblemCase, int)’ is protected
A.hpp:99:46: error: within this context
```

note that names are changed so numbers of characters in error log are incorrect.

Comment: Can you give the full error?

Comment: You can always declare the inner class inline, and define it out of line later.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Exception` is protected, which means that only classes derived from `Exception` is allowed to use it. The class `A` is not derived from `Exception`, which is why you are getting the error on line 99.

Edit: Ok, so I took the above code, cleaned it up to make it compile, and I get the exact same error messages - good for a reproduction!

The solution I could fine is to remove the "protected" from the constructor and make is public. I can't find any other solution that actually works, and I'm not sure WHY it doesn't work as it is written.

```
class A {
    int SomeField;
    class Exception 
    {
    public: 
       enum ProblemCase { PB1, PB2 };
    public: 
       Exception( ProblemCase issue, int additionalData ) {  } 
    };
    inline Exception BuildException( Exception::ProblemCase issue ) {
        return Exception( issue, SomeField ); // line#99
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you want to forward declare Exception if it is the type returned by A's method BuildException? As far as I know Exception must be fully defined when A::BuildException appears.

Comment: Ah, good point. Not sure how to solve it then. Unless, of course, the first half of my solution solves both.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with mere rearrangement of declarations. Some *major* restructuring is required.

```
class A {

  public:
    class Exception;

  private:
    class AHelper
    {
      public:
        friend class A;
        class ExceptionBase
        {
          public:
            typedef enum {Something} ProblemCase;
        };
      private:
        inline static Exception BuildException(ExceptionBase::ProblemCase issue, int something);
    };

    int SomeField;

  public:    
    class Exception : public AHelper::ExceptionBase
    {
      public:
        using AHelper::ExceptionBase::ProblemCase;
      protected:
        Exception(ProblemCase issue, int additionalData) {}
        friend Exception AHelper::BuildException(ProblemCase, int);
    };

    inline Exception BuildException(Exception::ProblemCase issue);
};

inline A::Exception A::AHelper::BuildException(A::Exception::ProblemCase issue, int something)
{
    return A::Exception(issue, something);
}

inline A::Exception A::BuildException(A::Exception::ProblemCase issue)
{
    return AHelper::BuildException(issue, SomeField);
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: You lost the second argument of Class A's BuildException.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an "academic" example, closest I could get. Note: NOT recommended.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A { // line#10
    /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
    // more fields of the following functionality exist, storing data about object A's state.
    int SomeField;

    class Exception;

    template < typename T >
    inline Exception BuildException( T issue );

    class Exception {
        /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
        public: enum ProblemCase { FIRST /*(...) */ };
        protected: Exception( ProblemCase issue, int additionalData ) { /*(...)*/ } // line#29
        // accepted by clang, not by g++??
        // friend Exception A::BuildException<ProblemCase>( ProblemCase ); // line#34

        // accepted by both
        template < typename T >
        friend Exception A::BuildException( T ); // line#34
    };
};

// there's no need to define it outside the class
// (I originally used an explicit specialization)
template < typename T >
A::Exception A::BuildException( T issue ) {
    // optional
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<T>::type, Exception::ProblemCase>::value, "Wrong type!");

    return Exception( issue, SomeField ); // line#99
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.BuildException(A::Exception::FIRST);
}
```